# Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\AppX1\signin.php on line 6

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm having an issue with my php script. Very new to php so I know it's not the best. The following errors occur when submitting my form.

> Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\AppX1\signin.php on line 6
>   Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\AppX1\signin.php on line 7
>   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() in C:\xampp\htdocs\AppX1\signin.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\AppX1\signin.php on line 13

I've read a few posts saying to use a `isset` method although I'm not sure where to put this or if it applies to my situation.

```
<form action="signin.php" id="signInForm">
    <fieldset>
        <label class="fieldLabel" for="uname">Email Address</label>
        <input class="fieldInput" type="text" id="uname" name="username">
        <label class="fieldLabel" for="pword">Password</label>
        <input class="fieldInput" type="password" id="pword" name="password">
        <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

---

```
<?php

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];


  // sql injection prevention
  $username = stripcslashes($username);
  $password = stripcslashes($password);
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

  //connect to server and select SQLiteDatabase
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("user");

  //query db for user
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user where email = '$username' and password = '$password'")
            or die("Failed to query database ".mysql_error());

  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  if ($row['email'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password) {
    echo "Login Success!".$row['email'];
  }
  else {
    echo "Login Failed";
  }



?>
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<form action="signin.php" id="signInForm">`

You are missing your method for form. 
`<form action="signin.php" id="signInForm" method="post" >`

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() in C:\xampp\htdocs\AppX1\signin.php:13

If you use PHP 7, `mysql_real_escape_string` function is removed. Try to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead and make sure you have loaded `mysqli` PHP module in php.ini (use `phpinfo()` or `php -I | grep -i mysqli` from command line to check if the module has been loaded)

Comment: Please learn to use prepared statements.